# Is it possible to share an object between HTTP requests on the server side (PHP, Symfony)?

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I want to improve a performance of a web service, which needs to create a stateless but very large (in terms of a memory) object. This takes quite a lot of time - 0.3s. Replacing a constructor with loading a serialized object improved the time to 0.1s. Is there a way to keep such an object in http server memory (PHP, Symfony 4) and use it in different http requests?

Comment: Yeah using rest as json format

Comment: You could use Memcached, you could use tmpfs/ramfs, you could use shared memory extension, ... there are a lot of ways to buffer things. The question itself is considered off-topic on Stackoverflow, because it is too broad and/or attracting opinion.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu "rest as json format" JSON is just a format (as you recognized). A format does not improve performance. REST has also nothing to do with performance.

Comment: Have you considered running your microservice in Swoole? This way your object could stay in memory all the time.

Comment: @DanFromGermany then serialization would help, if the languge is same...

Comment: @AnimeshSahu "serialization" is such a generic word. He is doing serialization here and there. Please be specific in how things could help the OP, but stop posting generic buzzwords without anything to back them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: This is usually done with a key-value storage like Redis or Memcache. But that doesn't get rid of the time it takes to unserialize which is probably the bottleneck here.

It depends what your setup is. The usual "web server answers a request and boots up PHP via either mod_php, CGI or FPM" can't do this. HTTP is stateless and PHP processes are isolated from each other. If you start your own server directly with PHP with something like [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org), you can share memory because your application will always be "up", much akin to a Java server process. But that changes the whole programming paradigm as suddenly you will have to take care of memory leaks, multithreading and such.